# How can you program a Liftmaster garage door opener when there is no "B" button?

Tags: garage-door-opener, remote-control

According to the Liftmaster manual, to program the garage door opener, which is required if the LEARN BUTTON was held down 6 seconds or more and ERASED the stored code, one must:

1. Remove the cover from the Lighted Door Control
2. Press and hold the button on the hand-held remote that you wish to operate your garage door.
3. While holding the remote button, press and hold the "A" button on the Lighted Door Control.
4. Continue holding both buttons while you press the "B" button on the Lighted Door Control (all three buttons are held).
5. Release buttons when the motor unit lights blink.  It has learned the code.  If light bulbs are not installed, two clicks will be heard.

PROBLEM:
The code was erased, so the above procedure must be followed.
However, the original Lighted Door Control broke apart last year and was replaced by a simple non-lighted doorbell button that has no "B" button.  There is no Home Depot or equivalent anywhere near where I live, so I cannot run out and buy a new Lighted Door Control.

QUESTIONS:

1. How can I Program the Liftmaster garage door opener and remote without a Lighted Door Control that has both an "A" and a "B" button.
2. Can more than one hand-held remote control the same garage door opener?

Comment: There should be a colored button (yellow, orange, red) on the garage door motor, behind the lamp shade.  You should be able to follow the alternate instructions for programming the new remote using that colored button, instead of the ones on the wall-mounted keypad.  Your new remote instructions will say to try this, then try that, but if that doesn't work to use the colored button and they will tell you how.   You could tell us the model # of the motor, or post a picture of it with the lamp shade open, showing all the wires and buttons on the motor.

Comment: You can edit your question to add the model number and any photos, and confirm that your instructions include an alternate way using the colored button.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed a new Chamberlain opener. The only difference between Chamberlain, LiftMaster and Crafstman brands are the color and the name printed on them. (i.e., they're all made by Chamberlain.) Having a program/learn button on the wall-mounted, wired remote was a novelty for me, as neither of my previous 2 openers had that.

As jay613 noted in his comment, mine *also* has programming/adjustment buttons under one of the light covers on the motor, just like both of my old ones did. I'm quite certain that yours will, as well, and you can use those buttons just like you would use the buttons on the wall-mount remote.

Once you figure out how to get the first remote programmed, (check out their website for your model, or, if necessary, hit up their online chat - they're quite helpful - they'll even wait while you run from the computer to the garage to try their instructions), programming additional remotes is exactly the same process. You can program wall-mounted, battery-powered numeric keypad remotes (you know, mount it outside the garage door, enter a code, garage door opens); visor mounted 1-, 2- or 3-button remotes; you can even program it to respond to the HomeLink buttons (usually) on the sun visor of your car (if it's so equipped). I'm sure there's an upper limit to how many remotes it will respond to, but I'm at 5 and haven't hit it.